# Multiple textareas

Tags: javascript, textarea

how can I reset multiple textareas to their default values (texts)? Is it possible without giving them specific class? I found only solution for one text input, but no successful with multiple textareas on 1 page, reseted by function.

```
<html>  
<body>
<textarea rows="1" cols="30">Hello World</textarea><br/>
<textarea rows="1" cols="30">Hello Second World</textarea><br/>

<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

<script>

            function reset() {
                document.querySelectorAll('textarea').value = <!--Default Value-->
                            }
                           
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put them in a `<form>` and call `form.reset()`... (or use `<input type="reset" />` to do it for you)

Comment: I need to stay with textareas unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
Address:<br>
<textarea id="myTextarea">
342 Alvin Road
Ducksburg</textarea>

<textarea id="myTextarea2">
Value 2</textarea>

<p>Click the button to change the contents of the text area.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myTextarea").value = "Txt1";
  document.getElementById("myTextarea2").value = "Txt2";
}
</script>
```

---

### Edit to match the use case in the comment

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea), textarea does not have a value property.

When the page loads the default value for a textarea is whatever the value in between some value. Therefore when the user changes it we don't have a way to find the original value.

To Overcome that we need somekind of a mechanism to store the default value

In your case if you have a lot of elements (Textareas), using a data attribute will help us to identify the default value after the page loads and the user changes the values

So use the following example

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="30" data-default="Default Val">Hello World</textarea><br/>
<textarea rows="1" cols="30" data-default="Default Val1">Hello World</textarea><br/>
<textarea rows="1" cols="30" data-default="Default Val2">Hello World</textarea><br/>

<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

<script>

            function reset() {
                
                var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
                    for(i =0; i < textareas.length; ++i){
                        textareas[i].value = textareas[i].getAttribute('data-default');
                    }   
                }
                           
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for respond. This would work with few of textareas, but unfortunately I have dozens of them in page and this script would be unnecessarily extensive. I just need to select all textareas in page and set their value to default...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, which is working correctly :) 

Is there any way to evade manually writing data-default attribute for each textarea? Like JS for set data-default as current value of certain textarea on start of page?

Comment: You can think of the same process in reverse order. Give it a shot and let us know how it goes

Comment: It can be easily done with textareas[i].setAttribute("data-default", textareas[i].value); :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the js script like below:

```
    function reset() {
        document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach((elem) => elem.value = "Desiered value");
    }
```

Or you can use an HTML placeholder and make the textarea value empty.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to reset textarea to default text = Hello world & Hello second world. Not to put custom value to all of textareas...